# Scheduling from thread in kernel space

Tags: c, multithreading, linux-kernel, scheduling

I wrote a netfilter module, in which I had to write an extra thread to clean up a data structure in regular basis. I used `schedule()` function after each round of clean up was done from the thread. Before using semaphore locks it was working just fine except `"General Protection Fault"` was occurring. So I used semaphores to lock and unlock the data structure during both `insert` and `delete` operation. Now it is showing a bug telling `"BUG: Scheduling while atomic"`. After searching in Google I got that it is showing because of explicit call of `schedule()` function where it should not be called.

What are the ways to resolve it? Is there any other way in which the thread will yield the CPU to other threads?

Comment: What do you mean by "extra thread"? Did you create a kernel thread?

Comment: yeah. I created a kernel thread beside main thread.

Comment: Would've been nice, if you've posted code snippet. Without looking at code can't give any suggestion, but 1 thing you've to be careful that usages of kernel thread aren't like using userspace threads, they're expensive and need to be careful.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use semaphores in "atomic" context, in other words probably the function you're trying to use semaphores in is inside spin lock critical section (look for spin_lock() calls in parent functions). If my guess is right (i.e. your function is already protected by spin lock) you don't need any additional synchronisation primitives.

Comment: rakib, the code is farely big one. So I am afraid you will be frightened to see the code.

DanKruchinin and rakib, if you wish I can explain what I am doing in which way. Would I?

BTW, sorry for the late reply. I was out of internet zone.

Comment: @Md.TaufiqueHussain i dont think i can help u much without looking at the code, how you expecting to explain something with few lines which is fairly big and other thing is you're design might be ok, but code may faulty so looking at the code is necessary. BTW, you can also try what Dan has suggested, 1) you're sleeping on atomic context ; 2)GPE usually happens due to memory access violation or there maybe some protection violations ...

Comment: Can you please give me some outline of common problems regarding memories for which GPF can occur? I mean, I know invalid memory access may lead to GPF but what action in kernel can lead to that type of scenerio?

Comment: @Md.TaufiqueHussain Whenever a GFP happens it triggers a fault (kind of interrupt, #13 as per intel cpu manual) and then kernel handles the fault by killing that faulty process. So, it CPU which triggers the problem and then kernel handles it. CPU has co-processor (MMU) which does all these calculations...

Answer (score 0):

So a basic summary (can't give a detailed answer for the reasons specified in the other comments):

A semaphore or mutex will attempt to grab a lock, and if it is unattainable, it will allow something else to run while it is waiting (this is done through the `schedule()` call).  A spinlock, on the other hand, is a locking mechanism that constantly tries to grab a lock until and does not relinquish control until it is succesful (note: there are also spinlock_irq_save, etc, which prevent you from being interrupted by an isr as well.  You can look these up).

As far as atomic goes, that means that the kernel is unable to allow another process to run in the background.  If you are in an interrupt for example, the kernel cannot allow someone else to run due to stack management.  If you are within a spinlock, the kernel cannot allow someone else to run, because if it it schedules another process waiting on the spinlock, you could get in a deadlock situation.   You can tell if you're atomic by using the `in_atomic()` macro.

For your case, you mention an insert and delete function which are obviously called (at least some of the time) from atomic context.  If these are only being called from an atomic context, then you can use a spinlock and be done with it.  If these are being called from both, you can use spinlock_irq_save (which prevents interrupts from interrupting the spinlocked-area).  Again, be careful about disabling interrupts for to long a time.

It is also possible to defer the freeing until later if there is something in the freeing, which you don't want to do from atomic context.  In this case, create a spin-lock-protected linked list which is poulated by your delete.   Then in your thread, you pop items off the list, and free them there.  For insertion, do the malloc before locking the list.

Hope this helps.

John